# Subquery in dynamodb for mutiple table with condional

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have 3 tables in dynamodb, I need to check like in first table lets say table1.column1='test' value exists then only go to second table to check table2.column2='value' else just send back response 'not exists in table1'. Similarly if value exists in table2 then only go to 3rd table like table3.column3 = 'value1' else provide message 'not exists in table2' and finally if value not exists in table3 then send 'not exists in table3'. This I need to implement in one query instead of multiple queries.

I have tried with multiple query but I need one query and one execution.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing here defies NoSQL norms. Related data should live together, so the data in each table should reside in a single table and you should be able to achieve your access pattern in a single request, or 2 at most.

Your current usage across 3 tables will force you to read each item. To save time I suggest you just do a BatchGetItem and read all 3 items and figure out what you need to do on the client side.